# What's the motivation or intuition of defining the regularity of measures in Measure Theory?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, intuition, motivation

In Measure Theory, the **regularity** of measures is defined as:

In any topological space $ \left(\Omega,\tau\right) $ , $ \mu $ is a measure on it; $ \mu $ is **inner regular**:

$$ \forall A\subseteq\Omega, \mu\left( A \right) = \sup\left\{ \mu\left(K\right) ; K\subseteq A , K \text{ is compact} \right\} $$

$ \mu $ is **outer regular**:

$$ \forall A\subseteq\Omega, \mu\left( A \right) = \inf\left\{ \mu\left(O\right) ; A\subseteq O , O \text{ is open} \right\} $$

and $ \mu $ is regular if and only if it is inner and outer regular simultaneously.

These definitions helped connect the measure structure and topological structure in a space $ \Omega $ that has these two structures.

But why? Why do we have these concepts rather than not?

I, as a noob in measure theory, the only reason I know is that the Lebesgue measure in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ fulfils these definitions, thus we can *approximate* any subset by open or compact (in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ those who will be equivalent with *bounded and closed*) sets in the meanings of measure, and I do know that compactness is so good since there exists naturally a finite cover and covers are important in measure theory, but I'm not entirely convinced buy just that. So my questions are:

1. Is it the main reason for defining the *regularity* of measures? If so, then why is it so important to *approximate* sets by open or closed sets?
2. If not, what's the main motivation for defining **regular** measures?
3. Why do we call such measures ***regular***?

The last question is a little bit more terminology or etymology, not strictly in the domain of Maths, I don't know if it's appropriate in this forum, but I insist on asking you for help. Thank you very much in advance for any comment on any of my questions, if my questions aren't so stupid or untimely...

Nice day~

Comment: To (partially) answer your first question: this property is important in proving things about general measurable sets or about our measure by looking first at the open sets or compact sets (which are very nice). Suppose you have to prove something about a measure $\mu$. By first looking at open bounded intervals, you get a much easier problem. Next step any open set is the countable union of disjoint bounded open intervals. Next, outer regularity allows you to approximate $\mu(A)$ by $\mu(O)$ for $O \supset A$ and open, etc.

Comment: As another example, we often want to integrate functions with respect to measures. Functions are usually better behaved on compact sets (e.g., extreme value theorem) and so it's often useful to approximate the integral of a function over some measurable set as the integral of that function over a compact set, and then take a sequence of compact sets that approximate the set we are actually interested in. For all of this to work, we need to know that the measure interacts well with this approximation by compact sets; regularity is exactly ensuring this is true.

Comment: One way to think about it is "Consistent == regular" : What that means is that , informally , measuring things from inside will match measuring things from outside. Earth/Cube/room/rectangle viewed from space/outside should have same volume/area/length when measured from inside.